# Taylor series expansion of sin(x)

Tags: calculus

I understand that Taylor series expansion for $\sin(x)$ is derived as follow: 
$$
\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...
$$
Now, what exactly is the first, second, and third term?
Is the first term just $\sin(x) = x$?
Is the second term $\sin(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}$?

Comment: You're question isn't clear at all.

Comment: @Mattos The question isn't written well, but it can be reasonably inferred what OP is asking. He is essentially asking whether or not the $n$th term in the Taylor expansion of $\sin$ refers to the $n$th term _including_ the zero terms or _excluding_ them.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I don't think so. I guess he is asking if the $n^{th}$ "term" is the sum of the $n$ first terms, i.e. the polynomial. Which it is not, of course.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the Taylor expansion at $0$ of the function $\sin(x)$, the even powers of $x$, i.e. the "missing" terms,  are  zero because  $\sin(x)$ is an odd function:
$$
\begin{align}\sin(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{D^k(\sin(x))_{x=0}}{k!}\cdot x^k
\\&=\sin(0)+\cos(0)x+\frac{-\sin(0)}{2!}\cdot x^2+\frac{-\cos(0)}{3!}\cdot x^3+
\frac{\sin(0)}{4!}\cdot x^4+\frac{\cos(0)}{5!}\cdot x^5+o(x^5)
\\&=\underbrace{0+x+0\cdot x^2-\frac{x^3}{3!}+0\cdot x^4+\frac{x^5}{5!}}_{\text{polynomial expansion up to the $5$-th term }}+o(x^5).
\end{align}$$

Comment: So, here specifically, where does the 3 term has been derived?

Comment: I am sorry. This is exactly the question I am asking. Where is the 3rd term? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: The $n$-term is the term with $x^n$, so the $3$rd term is  $-x^3/3!$. The expansion up to the $3$rd term or $3$rd order is $x- x^3/3!$.

Comment: Say, If I where told to approximate the Taylor expansion of sin(x) to 4th term I would just use this: x - x^3/3!, correct?

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: This is clear. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you know Euler's formula
$e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$,
the power series
$e^x
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$,
and don't mind using
complex expressions 
to get real results,
then
$$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}
=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))-(\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x))
=2i\sin(x)
$$
so
$$\sin(x)
=-i(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2
,$$
and
$$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(ix)^n-(-ix)^n}{n!}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ((i^n)-(-i)^n)\dfrac{x^n}{n!}
$$
and,
with period 4,
$$(i^n)-(-i)^n
=1-1, i-(-i), -1-(-1), -i-(i)
=0, 2i, 0, -2i
$$
so
$-i/2$ times this is
$0, 1, 0, -1$.

The power series is therefore
$$x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\dfrac{x^5}{120}-\dfrac{x^7}{5040}...
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
.$$

Comment: Right. Is the fourth term just x-x^3/6?

Comment: Yes. All the even terms are zero. For cosine, all the odd terms are zero.

Answer (score 0):

*Terms* are the members of a summation (whatever the formula) and they are enumerated in the order of their appearance (left to right, starting from first)

- $x$ is the first term,
- $-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}$ is the second term,
- $\dfrac{x^5}{5!}$ is the third term.

When speaking of a polynomial, a term is said of the $n^{th}$ *degree* depending on the power of the variable. So here there are no terms of even degree and

- $x$ is the first degree term,
- $-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}$ is the third degree term,
- $\dfrac{x^5}{5!}$ is the fifth degree term.

Now a Taylor expansion is written up to a remainder term, with as many terms as you like. The word *order* is used and equals the highest degree. So you can say

- $\sin(x)=x+r_1(x)$ is the first order expansion,
- $\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+r_3(x)$ is the third order expansion,
- $\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}+r_5(x)$ is the fifth order expansion.

---

Similarly, for the cosine you would have

First term $1$, second term $-\dfrac{x^2}2$, third term $\dfrac{x^4}{4!}$, and zero$^{th}$ order development/expansion $1$, second order $1-\dfrac{x^2}2$, fourth order $1-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}$.

Comment: So there is no 4th degree term?

Comment: @WinoPaz: what do you mean, your question is ambiguous ?

Comment: I guess you can understand me better after I write this. The thing is that I am actually calculating the exact value when sin(3.14159) to the 4th term and I am struggling with understanding until what degree of the equation I should use.

Comment: @WinoPaz: if you read my answer carefully, you should know what the fourth term will be. And your sentence "the exact value when sin(3.14159) to the 4th term" is completely meaningless.

Comment: Right. There is no even term. Thank you!