# Find relation between p and q if f(x) is continuous?

Tags: continuity

[image]

I feel that p>q because lt (x/sinx) = 1 and if p>q f(x) is continuous.But given answer is p>0.

Can someone explain how is b the answer ?

Comment: Note that for $ p = 1 $ and $ q = 5 $, the function is not continuous around $ 0 $. So (B) cannot be right answer, can you check your answer key again?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
To answer this question, you could look at the [Taylor Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561212/taylor-series-expansion-of-sinx) of $ \sin{x} $, which can be represented as -

$$ \sin{x} = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} ........$$

Now, note that your function will be continuous at zero only if:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0) = 0 $$

Now, for $ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) $ to be equal to $0$, the numerator has to decrease **faster** than the denominator.

The highest power of $x$ in the numerator is $p$, while the highest power in the denominator can be found using the Taylor Series as mentioned above and it is $q$.

Therefore, $ \lim_{x \to 0} x^{p} < \lim_{x \to 0} x^{q} $, which corresponds to $p > q$ which is option **A**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have :

$$ \dfrac{x^p}{\sin(x)^q} \simeq \dfrac{x^p}{x^q}=x^{p-q}$$

which tend to zero **if and only if** $$ p>q $$ which is the right answer (a)